# How to get a smartphone to communicate with a car battery?

Tags: android, ios

I'm trying to break the current of a car battery for an x period of time. Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get an arduino board and a relay capable of switching a 12v circuit. Also get a wifi / bluetooth add on board so you can communicate with the arduino from your smartphone platform of choice.

[Here is an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoDIEOXlXNQ) of an arduinos capability, this particular example is using bluetooth.